# Why might bugzilla only accept bugs for one product?

Tags: bugzilla

I've set up multiple products on a new Bugzilla installation, but only one of them is used. On the "new bug" page, it is automatically selected and there isn't even a drop-down list to pick one of the others.

When editing a bug, the drop-down list for Product does appear, but has only one entry.

Presumably the other products are misconfigured in some way, but I can't see how. I've never done this before, so I have almost certainly done *something* wrong.

Does anyone know what the rules are for when a product in bugzilla is valid, or anywhere I can look (log files, scripts I can run) to find out why my configuration is not working?

Comment: Part of the problem is that unless I refresh, I am seeing cached pages, so it looks like what I changed didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason a product would not be visible is that the user you are logged in as does not have permissions to see it or enter bugs into it. Bugzilla's permissions system is complex, but look and see whether the product is in any groups, and if so, the user needs to be in all the same ones.

Or it could be caching, as you suggested.

Gerv

Comment: Yeah that was it. I see now that if you select "Entry" permission for more than one group in a product, then a user has to be in ALL of those groups to enter a bug for the product, not just one of them.

Because I set up a group intended for external testers to enter bugs and I wasn't in that group, then most of the products became effectively invisible to me.